# links from an array to external variables?

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

How to make references to external variables from an array?
For example: if I change the array values ​​then
these values ​​should be stored in variables
referenced by array elements.
I tried to implement this idea, but it didn't work :(

**According to my idea:**

1. `echo $one` should output `1`
2. `echo $two` should output `2`

   ```
   $one;
   $two;
   $link = [$first = &$one,  $second = &$two];
   $link[0] = 1;
   $link[1] = 2;
   echo $one;  // does not show 1 
   echo $two;  // does not show 2
   ```

Comment: Why `$first = &$one, $second = &$two`? You should just be able to create an array like: `$link = [&$one, &$two];` and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should structure your code like so:

```
    $one;
    $two;
    //you did not initialize the $first and $second if you want them to be the keys like so
    //$link = [$first => &$one,  $second => &$two]; 
    $link = [&$one, &$two];
    $link[0] = 1;
    $link[1] = 2;
   //if you need to initialize them to another variable then do
   //And it should come after you have assigned a value to $link[0] and $link[1]
    $first = $link[0];
    $second = $link[1];
    echo $one;  // show 1 
    echo $two;  // show 2

    echo $first;  // show 1 
    echo $second;  // show 2
```

Comment: I wanted to use the option with additional variables, but an error occurred. This does not work.

`$one;
$two;

$link = [$first => &$one,  $second => &$two]; 

$first = $link[0];
$second = $link[1];

$link[0] = 1;
$link[1] = 2;

echo $one;  
echo $two;  `

Comment: Setting up your array like this: `$link = [$first => &$one,  $second => &$two];` make `$first` and `$second` the array keys and not initializing the variable.

Comment: If you need to assign `$first` and `$second` to the array item `$one` and `$two` and get the values you just assigned them(`$link[0] = 1; $link[1] = 2;`), then take a look at the edited answer where I assigned `$first = $link[0];`  and `$second = $link[1];` after I have set the value of the array items